# calling pg-function using npgsql

Tags: npgsql

**A very simple function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stzh.test() RETURNS refcursor AS $BODY$

declare 
   outcursor refcursor;
begin
   OPEN outcursor 
   FOR SELECT '-1' As "value1";

   return outcursor;

end;$BODY$

  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

**Code to call the function:**

```
Dim pCon As NpgsqlConnection
        Dim pCommand As NpgsqlCommand
        Dim pDataReader As IDataReader

        pCon = New NpgsqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PG_connection"))
        pCon.Open()
        pCon.BeginTransaction()

        pCommand = pCon.CreateCommand
        With pCommand
            .CommandText = "stzh.test"
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            pDataReader = .ExecuteReader
        End With

        While pDataReader.Read
            Console.WriteLine(pDataReader.GetName(0))
        End While
```

Executing this code writes the name of the function ("test") to the console. I was expecting the name of the column ("value1") to be written to the console.

What am I missing?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason for your function to return a cursor, read the basic PostgreSQL documentation and samples for creating functions.

Comment: i'm perfectly aware of this! my function is actualy far more complex and definitly needs a cursor. I just used this simple function in this example as my question points to the communication between npgsql and the function. the content of the function isn't relevant at all...